# Erlang and sqlite

Tags: sql, erlang, sqlite

I create sqlite db with Erlang:

```
    sqlite3:open(user_db, [in_memory]),
    TableInfo = [{user, text, [not_null]}, {password, text, [not_null]}, {domain, text, [not_null]}],
    ok = sqlite3:create_table(user_db, users, TableInfo)
```

My table:

```
user     password   domain

 shk       qwerty   localhost\

 admin     qwerty   localhost\
```

I try select user whch name admin for example:

```
sqlite3:sql_exec(user_db, "SELECT user FROM users WHERE user = shk;")
```

I get error:

=ERROR REPORT==== 21-Feb-2011::22:38:51 ===
sqlite3 driver error: no such column: shk

But for example if i try:

```
sqlite3:sql_exec(user_db, "SELECT user FROM users WHERE password = qwerty;")
```

it's ok. What's wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string values should be enclosed with parens as follows:

```
SELECT user FROM users WHERE user = 'spongebob';
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much it works. But why other '' work without ' '

Comment: @shk: Don't know for sure yet. Could you add in your question what rows does the second query return? I suspect it returns all rows, but if you add another row, where the password differs, it will be returned, too.